# How can I find the places of system calls of my program?

Tags: linux, debugging, strace

From strace manual:

```
-i Print the instruction pointer at the time of the system call.
```

I straced my programm:

```
strace -i prog
```

As a result I got a lot of system calls. One of them:

```
[000da49c] open("./rabbit.o", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

But disassembled instruction at this address of prog doesn't call any syscall (hte editor):

```
da49c !   mov         r7, ip
```

What is wrong? How can I find the places of system calls of my program?

P.S. Architecture of my device doesn't support GDB-command catch syscall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cite the Bugs section of the "strace" man-page:

```
The -i option is weakly supported.
```

Another tip which might help you: Do you looked at the previous code?
The IP at point of putting it out, already points to the NEXT instruction, after the syscall.
So you should check the instruction before `da49c`.

Comment: it is:       da498 !   svc         0x00000000  .  
It could be syscall I should check it. Thank you for reply.